# combine csv files using cut to select a column and paste to make a combination of the files

Tags: linux, bash, csv

I have a directory with sub directories with many csv files with two columns (a word and its count). I want to use command line tools like cut and paste to combine all these sorted (lexicographically). I need to cut the second column (count) and paste it into a combo file.

I got this working well with two files:

```
cut -d , -f 2  sorted_2.csv | paste -d , sorted_1.csv > combo_2.csv

word1,1187177,1229568
word2,279525,290798
word3,81756,85163...
```

However, when I try :
cut -d , -f 2  sorted_2.csv sorted_3.csv | paste -d , sorted_1.csv > combo_2.csv

I got:

```
word1,1187177,1229568
word2,279525,290798
word3,81756,85163... 
,1187177
,279525
,81756...
```

The new column got stacked below and not like this:

```
word1,1187177,1229568,1187177
word2,279525,290798,279525
word3,81756,85163, 81756...
```

I tried this:

```
paste file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv | cut -f 2 > combo_3.csv
```

But got the sorted file 2 back inside the combo_3.

What I am doing wrong?

Thank you all.

Paulo

Comment: Check your files for dos line endings. `What I am doing wrong?` I do not understand, what do you _want_ to do?

Answer (score 3):

> I want to use command lines tools like cut and past to combine all the sorted (lexicographicaly). I need to cut the second column (count) and paste in a combo file.

Then cut from all the files, not from one. And paste the results - one cut for each file.

```
paste -d, <(cut -d, -f2 sorted_1.csv) <(cut -d, -f2 sorted_2.csv) <(cut -d, -f2 sorted_3.csv)
```

> how could I use this command in 20000 csvs at same time?

```
find ....all_the_files... |
{
    IFS= read -r file1
    cut -d, -f2 "$file1" > output.txt
    while IFs= read -r file; do
        paste -sd, output.txt <(cut -d, -f2 "$file") > output.txt.tmp
        mv output.txt.tmp output.txt
    done
}
```

Comment: I there how could I use this command in 20000 csvs at same time?

Comment: Take 2 first files. Merge. Output. Take the output and the 3rd file. Merge. Output. Take the output and 4th file. Merge. Output. Repeat for all files.

Comment: I will try that thanks by your time . Paulo